# Android big text notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I trying to use big text style with NotificationCompat.Builder it's work fine in android 4.4.4 but i have a problem in Android 4.0.3 - my notification is not expanded

What i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that expanded notifications are not available on platforms prior to Android 4.1. To learn how to handle notifications for Android 4.1 and for earlier platforms, read the section Handling compatibility

[expanded layout to a notification document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Expanded notifications were introduced in Android 4.1 (JellyBean). On prior versions you will get the original notification style. The purpose of `NotificationCompat.Builder` is to let you write code that compiles on every version of Android and gracefully handles whatever version it ends up being installed on.